# R and Aspell Error Message

Tags: r, text-mining, aspell

I'm trying to get the [aspell](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/aspell.html) function working in R on Windows 7. I've installed the Aspell binary and dictionary from here: http://aspell.net/win32/ and it works fine outside of R (ie I get a desktop icon which I can drag and drop text files onto and the spell check works as expected). I've added C:\Program Files\Aspell\bin to the system variable path in Environmental Variables.

When I run aspell in R:

```
x <- as.factor("my spelling is turrible")
aspell(x)
```

I get this error message:

```
Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "r") :
  cannot open file 'C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp8Oulj4\xshell2b479b97856': No such file or directory
```

I've tried a couple of different recommendations but nothing seems to be working. These being checking that factors are being used ([Converting to factors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11511872/1409652)) and checking if folder security is set to 'Full Control' ([Aspell Dictionary can't be opened](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1764635/1409652)).

Does anyone have any pointers on where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Did you reboot after updating the path environment variable?  Windows is flaky about letting software know about changes until you reboot.

Comment: I tried rebooting and have since rebooted again. Still no luck. I can call Aspell from command prompt by typing aspell which I couldn't before I added it to environmental variables.